# MySQL replication, master only replicate a portion data to slave

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

I have a master/slave mysql deployment.
And success to do replication.
But after several weeks. Only a portion of data replicate to slave.
It's not the network. Because it replicate indeed but a portion lose.

I've check `show master status\G; and show slave status\G;`

```
 Slave_IO_Running: Yes
 Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
```

and

```
Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000016
Read_Master_Log_Pos: 515965048
```

is OK also. master_log_pos is up to date with the master.

Notice. The table of master is MyISAM and the corresponding table of slave is InnoDB.
I don't think it's an issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of variables on the slave that effects replication.

On the slave it's the replicate-do-* and --replicate-ignore-*. You should read through that part of the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-slave.html)

Comment: I've checked the my.conf, but not relate. It's ok at first deployment. But only occur these days.